# Docker-machine swarm; how to open ports on VM

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

Trying out the new "swarm mode", following [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/swarm-tutorial/#/open-ports-between-the-hosts). I have created 3 VM's via `docker-machine create --driver virtual box <name>`. But how do I open ports on them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might work with `docker run -p <public-port>:<internal-port> <image>` executed on the node. However, since you want to run a swarm, I guess it is better to follow a good guide to [solve the routing mess here](https://medium.com/@lherrera/solving-the-routing-mess-for-services-in-docker-73492c37b335#.gcqalji3d). If you follow the author's suggestions, you need to create a swarm (i.e. the docker host cluster) first by the `docker-machine` commands, e.g.

```
docker-machine create --driver virtualbox swarm-1
docker-machine create --driver virtualbox swarm-2
```

setup swarm with

```
eval $(docker-machine env swarm-1)
docker swarm init --advertise-addr $(docker-machine ip swarm-1)
```

join the other machines (if there are any) with

```
eval $(docker-machine env swarm-2)
docker swarm join \ 
--token <yourtoken> 192.168.99.106:2377
```

where `<yourtoken>`is found in the output of the `docker swarm init` command.

Then the author suggests to create a network with something like

```
docker network create --driver overlay webnet
```

and publish the port by defining a service like

```
docker service create --name webapp --replicas=2 --network webnet --publish 80:8000 <yourdockerimage>
```

In this example, yourdockerimage is running a service internally on port 8000, which is mapped to the docker host port 80. Then, you can access the service e.g. by

```
curl http://<IP-address of any Docker swarm node>:80
```

Note, you can access the IP address of any Docker swarm node. Docker swarm will do the magic and will route the request to a container of this service, even if you have chosen the IP address of a node no container of this service is running on.