# Docker swarm mode routing mesh not work as expected

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I tried to create services in docker swarm model by following this [document](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/ingress/)

I created two nodes in the swarm:
[image]

Then create the deploy the service, I use `jwilder/whoami` here instead of `nginx` in the document,
`docker service create --name my-web --publish published=8888,target=8000 --replicas 2 jwilder/whoami`

Seems like they started successfully:
[image]

As the document said:

> When you access port 8080 on any node, Docker routes your request to
>   an active container.

SO in my opinion, I can access the `my-web` service from any of the node, however I found that only one node work:

[image]

What's going on?

Comment: Looks like the service was opened on port 8888, not 8080. Are you sure that one server does not have a separate (non-swarmed) instance of whoami running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be caused by ports being blocked between the nodes. The swarm mesh networking uses the "ingress" network to connect the published port to a VIP for the service. That ingress network is an overlay network implemented with vxlan. For that you need:

- TCP port 2377 for cluster management communications
- TCP and UDP port 7946 for communication among nodes
- UDP port 4789 for overlay network traffic

Reference: https://docs.docker.com/network/overlay/

It's possible for these ports to be blocked at many levels, including iptables, firewalls on the routers, and I've even seen VMware block this with their NSX tool that also implemented vxlan.

For iptables, I typically use the following commands:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2376 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2377 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 7946 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 7946 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m udp --dport 4789 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p 50 -j ACCEPT
```

The above will differ if you use firewalld or need to change firewall rules on the network routers.

Comment: I have thought it may be caused by the firewall too, however if that's true, how can the `worker1` node join the swarm? IMO, when it tried to join the cluster, it must have to communicate to the manager node(`default` in my case). Also, I am not sure the network should be set by the host or vbox?  When I search that I got this https://stackoverflow.com/a/39375757/306719. It create the network explicitly, and specify the network every time it create the service which is not mentioned in the document.

Comment: Overlay networking occurs over different ports and between different nodes than worker to manager scheduler communication.

Comment: OK, I will have a try.